# Single Sign-On In Chrome & Other Browsers For O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, sso

We have enabled auto-acceleration flag on our O365 Tenancy and single sign-on works in IE.

How do we get SSO working for other browsers with O365?

Comment: As per my knowledge, ADFS is best approach to make O365 as SSO.

Comment: ADFS is already in place & working for IE. SSO not working in other browsers in same underlying infrastructure.

Comment: did u tried to turn off the Enhanced Protection for Windows Authentication in IIS in the adfs ls folder?

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, you need to configure the 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris' setting for the ADFS federation URL you are using. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Enter 'about:config' in the URL bar in Firefox.
2. Click the 'I accept the risk!' button on the 'Here be dragons!' page that is shown
3. search for 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris' and then double-click this entry
4. Enter the base URL for the ADFS federation server that requests your username and password. This will be shown in the 'Authentication required' dialog that is shown when Firefox requests your username and password. If, for example, this dialog shows 'https://federation.domain.com', then this is what you should enter:
   [image: network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted.uris setting]
5. Open a new tab and navigate to your SharePoint Online site URL. During the login process, when SharePoint Online bounces you to your ADFS Federation URL for authentication, the browser will now automatically present your login credentials, and it should behave the same way that IE does.

For me, Chrome uses the same settings as IE without me having to make any configuration changes, so a default installation of Chrome at the current version automatically presents my credentials to my ADFS Federation server when I log into SharePoint Online.